# PHP Warning: Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to memcached-env-.jelasticloud.com:11211, Connection timed out (110)

Tags: jelastic

PHP Warning:  Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to memcached-env-.jelasticloud.com:11211, Connection timed out (110)

I use infobox hoster.
The can not fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
memcached-env-.jelasticloud.com
```

This hostname is incorrect. Please check it; it should be memcached-env-123456.jelasticloud.com (where "env-123456" is your chosen environment name, and jelasticloud.com is your hosting provider's allocated sub/domain for Jelastic environments).

You can also only connect to the memcached server from within your environment (it is restricted by firewall to only allow connections from other servers within the same environment), so please make sure that you're attempting to connect from a PHP server (Apache/Nginx) in the same Jelastic environment. (and that you've enabled the desired memcache/d PHP extension in your php.ini).